# Subtotal Group using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6gNu6/8/)

```
<table border="1" class="cssTable">
    <tr id="trGroup">
        <td>
            Black, Total <asp:Label ID="lblCount" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cssTd">
              A            
         </td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td class="cssTd">
              B            
         </td>
    </tr>   
    <tr id="trGroup">
        <td>
            White, Total <asp:Label ID="lblCount" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cssTd">
              X            
         </td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td class="cssTd">
              Y            
         </td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td class="cssTd">
             Z       
         </td>
    </tr>   
    </table>
```

I have to subtotal group.
means in above example Black have 2 Child
and White have 3 child

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the `id='trGroup'` to `class='trGroup'` (you're supposed to have unique id's), and then use the [nextUntil](http://api.jquery.com/nextuntil/) method.

```
$('.trGroup').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        subTotal = $this.nextUntil('.trGroup').length;
    $this.text($this.text() + subTotal);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/6gNu6/11/)

Comment: tewathia its awesome solution.i have to update label text .in your answer u have update tr text my label is inside td.So text displayed at center of tr.

Comment: @Means I didn't notice that my code was over-writing the `asp:Label`. See the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/6gNu6/14/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#trGroup').each(function() {
  var len;

  len = $(this).nextUntil('tr#trGroup').length

  // i think this **len** is what you require
})
```